# Weird behaviour with FVector

Tags: unreal-engine4, spawning

I have a little code snippet in UE4 c++ that is supposed to give me a bunch of FVectors in a grid.

However, printing out the FVectors gives me (0,0,0) every single time

```
FVector deltaLoc;
float xGap = 150;
float yGap = 150;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    //FCellRow row;
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("I, J:  %f, %f"), i, j);
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("newX, newY:  %f, %f"), xGap * i, yGap * j);
        deltaLoc.Set(xGap * i, yGap * j, 0);
        
        //deltaLoc.X = xGap * i;
        //deltaLoc.Y = yGap * j;
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("DeltaLoc %f %f %f"), deltaLoc.X, deltaLoc.Y, deltaLoc.Z);
}
```

The output looks like

> LogTemp: Warning: I, J:  0, 2
>
> LogTemp: Warning: newX, newY:  0, 300
>
> LogTemp: Warning: DeltaLoc 0 0 0

for all values of i and j. The first two log lines work fine. The third one stays the same.

Comment: I can't tell you this is the problem for certain but it's at-least a problem. `UE_LOG` ends up casting to the stated type, on the first two logs YOU are printing int s and suggesting they're floats which is not legal.

Comment: That seems to be the issue I was facing. Using the correct types in log message helps.